# How to send a multiple post request in a single batch?

Tags: json, odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

I am trying to send multiple POST requests in a single batch.

With these 3 requests we are setting the status on the Notification and Order --> Work Is Done, Complete and Close Report.
Like FIORI.

But in the SAP Gateway Client, only requests 1 and 3 are ok. The status for the Order is still the same.

Maybe one request is blocking the other?
Do I have to create different changesets? And how do I do that?

```
Request-URI:
/sap/opu/odata/sap/EAM_MALFUNCTION_MANAGE/$batch

Request:
--batch
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset

--changeset
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


POST C_MaintNotificationTPPerform_user_action?sap-client=320&MaintenanceNotification='100000001882'&DraftUUID=guid'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'&IsActiveEntity=true&Statusobject='OV100000675500000001'&Targetstatus='O030'&Eventconfiguration='1'&Reasoncodegroup=''&Reasoncode=''&Isadditionalreason=false HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
sap-contextid-accept: header
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
Content-Length: 626


--changeset
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


POST C_MaintNotificationTPPerform_user_action?sap-client=320&MaintenanceNotification='100000001882'&DraftUUID=guid'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'&IsActiveEntity=true&Statusobject='OR000004001747'&Targetstatus='0050'&Eventconfiguration='1'&Reasoncodegroup=''&Reasoncode=''&Isadditionalreason=false HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
sap-contextid-accept: header
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
Content-Length: 800


--changeset
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


POST C_MaintNotificationTPPerform_user_action?sap-client=320&MaintenanceNotification='100000001882'&DraftUUID=guid'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'&IsActiveEntity=true&Statusobject='QM100000001882'&Targetstatus='0051'&Eventconfiguration='1'&Reasoncodegroup=''&Reasoncode=''&Isadditionalreason=false HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
sap-contextid-accept: header
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
Content-Length: 755


--changeset--


--batch--
```

Comment: I will assume that your requests are okay being processed in any order and that you are triggering BAPIs on an SAP ECC ABAP client via a SAP oData service.

Without seeing your javascript code where you are triggering the requests, it's hard to address problem 1 (only 2 of 3 requests sending in the same batch). 

For problem 2 (nothing being updated), yes- I would try sending them in different changesets as you mentioned, processing in series. You can find more information here (setting "changeSetId"): https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/create

Comment: I have no javascript code. I'm testing this in SAP Gateway Client. I think there is no commit here.

See also Response (sap-message):

Comment: sap-message: {"code":"IW/085","message":"Auftrag 4001737 mit Meldung 100000001870 gesichert","severity":"success","target":"/#TRANSIENT#","details":[{"code":"IWO_BAPI2/128","message":"Nach SAVE-Methode muss COMMIT WORK oder ROLLBACK WORK ausgef\u00FChrt werden","longtext_url":"/sap/opu/odata/iwbep/message_text;o=S4HANA/T100_longtexts(MSGID='IWO_BAPI2',MSGNO='128',MESSAGE_V1='',MESSAGE_V2='',MESSAGE_V3='',MESSAGE_V4='')/$value","target":"/#TRANSIENT#","severity":"error"},{"code":"IWO_BAPI2/128","message":"Nach SAVE-Methode muss COMMIT WORK oder ROLLBACK WORK ausgef\u00FChrt werden","

Comment: longtext_url":"/sap/opu/odata/iwbep/message_text;o=S4HANA/T100_longtexts(MSGID='IWO_BAPI2',MSGNO='128',MESSAGE_V1='',MESSAGE_V2='',MESSAGE_V3='',MESSAGE_V4='')/$value","target":"/#TRANSIENT#","severity":"error"},{"code":"IM/268","message":"Meldung 100000001870 kann nicht abgeschlossen werden","longtext_url":"/sap/opu/odata/iwbep/message_text;o=S4HANA/T100_longtexts(MSGID='IM',MSGNO='268',MESSAGE_V1='100000001870',MESSAGE_V2='',MESSAGE_V3='',MESSAGE_V4='')/

Comment: $value","target":"/#TRANSIENT#","severity":"error"},{"code":"EAMS_BO/121","message":"Meldung 100000001870 wurde nicht abgeschlossen","target":"/#TRANSIENT#","severity":"error"}]}

Comment: Can this not be solved with different changesets? Unfortunately, I have no experience with this.